# Best/quickest way to convert to float

Tags: c#, floating-point

So I am trying to have input and output in float number.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter float number: ");
float number = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("{0}", number);
```

I see the problem that ReadLine will have format in string which will cause "Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'float' (CS0029)". Now, how do I convert string to float? I could use float.Parase:

```
string unformattedNumber;
float number;

Console.WriteLine("Enter float number: ");
unformattedNumber = Console.ReadLine();

number = float.Parse(unformattedNumber);

Console.WriteLine("{0}", number);
```

But is there any better way to convert in same line as ReadLine statement is at?

Comment: `number = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` -- there's also `float.TryParse` at your disposal.

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize I could use this there.

Comment: TryParse should be a bit faster when the string is not a valid number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TryParse` is the best way.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.tryparse.aspx

Answer (score 2):

float number = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); should work perfectly fine. In general you can compose function calls like that on the same line. Just don't get carried away -- make sure the meaning's clear. Sometimes it actually makes your code clearer, but if you do it too much, you end up with an unreadable thicket of code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with calling `float.Parse` is that if your input isn't a numeric value it will raise an exception and halt your program. As the user can enter anything at this point, you need to cater for that.

You could wrap the `float.Parse` in an exception handler but it would be better to use [`float.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.tryparse.aspx):

```
float result;
if (float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result))
{
    // Do stuff
}
```